# ED50s and LD50s

Tags: regression

Suppose that we are given 1000 doses between 0 and 10 and various ordinal values (1 = normal, 2 = critical condition, 3 = death). So  typical data points would of the form: $(5,1), (6,1), (10,3)$ etc.

What is the purpose of using regression to obtain LD50? Couldn't we just look at the data and see at what dose $50 \%$ of the animals died? I guess regression is used to obtain an estimate of the LD50 if the experiment was repeated multiple times with different doses?

Answer (score 6):

Flipping a fair coin doesn't always give exactly half heads and half tails, so a dose that happens to give 50% mortality in one experiment is not necessarily the true LD50. The regression includes information from all doses, both above and below the LD50, effectively interpolating to provide a more precise estimate of the LD50 with fewer animals used overall.